# MSAccess Datatype for Windows.System.Colors

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

What is the datatype for `Color` in MSAccess?

Comment: Access has this handy little thing called a HELP FILE. You can get there by hitting the F1 key in any color property in the property sheet of any Access object. The first paragraph of the help file gives the data type.

Comment: Are you using Access or Winforms? If Winforms, why do you care about Access properties?

Comment: Im using winforms. I forgot the help menu from msaccess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Long Integer (stores 4 bytes) in your database field and use `Color.ToArgb()` to get the integer value to store. Then, use `Color.FromArgb()` to create a color from the stored value.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. It doesn't involve Access. The Color property is a property of Access forms/reports/controls, but you're giving functions/methods for WinForms. Why would you store Access properties in a table and then use them in WinForms?

Comment: "Color", in this context, refers to System.Color in .NET. Rye seems to be using access as a backend store only.